# What word would you use for movement of bushes?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Say there's a small animal hidden among bushes and it causes the branches (if they can be called that) of the bushes to shake/move slightly. Now the sound of this could probably be described using *rustling*, but what word would use to describe the visual shaking/movement of the bushes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Trembling](http://www.google.com/dictionary?langpair=en%7Cen&q=trembling&hl=en&aq=f)

Comment: -1: Sorry, but bushes don't *tremble*!

Comment: Sorry, found a few references to trembling bushes. Duly upvoted your answer. +1 +1 !

Comment: I think only -aspens- tremble. Everything else rustles.

Answer (score 24):

According to [the Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rustling), you have it backwards: *rustling* refers to the movement, and the sound is thus implied. Personally I associate the word so strongly with both the movement and the sound that I would use it for either meaning.

So, stick with *rustling*.

To add to the other answers, a simple accurate word: *shaking*.

Comment: The dictionaries I checked (M-W, Oxford) indicate that he doesn't have it backwards.  They do agree that the sound and movement are closely associated though.

Comment: I agree *rustling* primarily relates to the sound, but movement is strongly implied (we wouldn't normally say something *rustled* if we could see it wasn't moving). But if I were looking through binoculars at a distant bush being disturbed by rabbit, I might say it *trembled*, rather than rustled - simply to avoid the inappropriate referemce to sound.

Comment: Technically you can't have sound without movement. You can have movement without sound (e.g. in a vacuum).

Comment: I like `rustling`.  It has the added benefit of conjuring up images of cowboys stealing cattle.  (Apparently the cowboys hide in the bushes and wait for a cow to wander past so they can shake the bushes and scare the cow... ...or something...)

Comment: I'd associated 'rustling' more with the sound, rather than just the movement. I like 'trembling' and 'quivering' (as Chris suggested below) though. Nothing else more specific?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the small animal happens to be a tortoise, the bushes might slowly flex as the tortoise lumbers between them.

Now suppose the animal is Tasmanian Devil, the bushes might flap violently as the Devil rushes through.

If a breeze is blowing the bushes might rustle.

Comment: And if that Devil wore a blue dress: [froufrou](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1249280#m_en_us1249280).

Answer (score 3):

I would use [quivering](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quivering).

Comment: See here: 
http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/836/exception-to-30-character-minimum-for-answers

Comment: I'd associate 'quivering' more with shaking, as in, 'quivering with fear'. Bushes?

Comment: Come to think of it, quivering does make sense in this context.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is hard to beat rustling but consider *swaying* or, more poetically, *shivering*.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of the rigidity of bushes I would fall on *shudder*; it fits well with the shape of the object.

Shudder also implies a geometric uneasiness, and pins and needles. A part of your question (the movement/sound of a leaf) is answered by *rustling*; *shudder*  is complementary as it pushes further into the character of bushes or shrubbery, and moves away from trees and more pliant plants.