# Can I say "trees were shaking" because of the wind? Or should it be "moving" or something else?

Tags: word-choice

> The strong wind blew and all the trees in our mini park were ...

What word should I use here? I mean that situation when the wind is strong enough to cause the trees to make some motions, yet not be uprooted (like in case of hurricane)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What word would you use for movement of bushes?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18488/what-word-would-you-use-for-movement-of-bushes)

Comment: "The trees are shaking" is extremely common and natural-sounding in spoken English, in my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One phrase that could be used is that *they were blown back and forth* or that they were *blown about*. This implies that there was movement due to the wind, but the trees weren't destroyed.

If the wind blew off the leaves, but the trees were intact, you can say that they were *blown bare*.

If you only want one word, you can say they were *shaken*. The [definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shake+%28another%27s%29+tree) writes:

> To cause to move to and fro with jerky movements.

So if the wind blew the trees around in no particular smooth motion, then they were *shaken by the wind*.

Answer (score 4):

You could also say the trees were *swaying*.

Comment: That makes me think of palm trees.

Comment: How about 'contorting'?

Comment: I'll upvote this. The question might well get closed as a duplicate, but the other one is about *bushes*, so I doubt it'll have "swaying".

Answer (score 0):

In a really string wind, trees can appear to be ***doubled over***.

***Bent*** would also work.

***Bowed*** can also be used (although "bowed" is used more when there is something in the branches (fruit or ice) that causes the tree to bend).

Answer (score -1):

One of the verbs that could decribe this include:

> Waving about/The trees in our park were waving about.

Also, it is common to say "waving their branches" :

> The tress in our park waved their branches when the wind blew.

But I think the above expression borders on the picturesque type.