# A word/phrase describing the sound of leaves?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have been describing a forest scene and there are only so many times I can use a form of the word **Rustling**.

Is there a word or phrase that can be used in place of this (It doesn't have to fit perfectly into place with **rustles/rustling/rustled**).

Any word or phrase that can describe the sound of:

1. Something moving through leaves
2. Leaves interacting with each other physically

Comment: leaves crackling? or maybe fluttering leaves?

Comment: Crunchy crackling sound..?Just like the sound of paper fluttering when a strong wind blows through it.

Comment: This question might be helpful: (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18488/what-word-would-you-use-for-movement-of-bushes) for the first point.

Comment: @JonyAgarwal fluttering is nice, and can work. :) thanks!

Comment: If possible, can you find a clip that contains that sound?

Comment: well you could just quit talking so much about how leaves sound...

Comment: @Oldcat I never thought of it like that! It's usual to aide in finding something

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Consider this lovely word, with its onomatopoeiac sibilance

> **susurrate**, meaning to rustle, murmur or whisper

from the Latin *susurrus* for whisper.

From *[The Decline and Fall of the British Empire](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z_3wbwj4OjsC&pg=PA263&dq=%22sussurating%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwA2oVChMI-tCNkZayyAIVhHY-Ch0fEQDN#v=onepage&q=%22sussurating%22&f=false)* by Piers Brendon:

> Especially alluring were the millions of date palms, with
>   diamond-shaped striations on their trunks, golden clusters of fruit
>   and an emerald whorl of fronds **sussurating** [sic] in the breeze.

Comment: You misspelled susurrate.

Comment: @JasperLocke Thank you.  Two *s*'s, two *r*'s, and two *u*'s.  And it seems I'm not alone.

Comment: No problem. I've been trying find this alternative spelling with two s's.

Comment: That is a lovely sounding word.

Comment: @JasperLocke The *OED* doesn't admit of the doubled *s*'s, which is supported by the etymology, but *ss* is all the Ngram viewer can find in print.   The google tells me that Italian doubles the *s*.  Go figure.

Comment: Darn it, you beat me to this word by a measly 11 hours.  Upvote for you.

Comment: _"onomatopoeiac sibilance"_ \*melts\*

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to only use synonyms for this, you can use unique metaphors or creative descriptions to get your point across. You can incite thought without directly describing it. For example, this can suggest the sound of leaves:

> The [wind] brought the forest to life.

Or

> The leaves were like a whispering audience.

Or

> The leaves sang a melody of comfort for those passing through the
>   forest.

You could come up with unlimited creative descriptions for the sounds of rustling in a forest. I'm sure your readers would actually prefer to discover the sound instead of being told so straightforwardly and blandly what it is. Of course there is the time for that but painting a picture is almost always more interesting and beautiful.

You can also find unique words that aren't necessarily synonyms of "rustling" to graft in emotions or moods, like this for a frightening scenario:

> The horror of the situation was only heightened by the lonesome sound
>   of the leaves scratching and scraping one another.

Or for a pleasant scenario:

> The leaves hummed and feathered as the women shuffled through the
>   bright forest.

We tend to hear things very differently depending on how we feel in a given situation. Describing your sounds like this can increase the drama and enhance the mood.

Answer (score 5):

***[to crackle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crackle)*** can be used referring to leaves, especially dry leaves:

> - to make slight, sudden, sharp noises, rapidly repeated.

The Free Dictionary

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leaves%20crackling%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleaves%20crackling%3B%2Cc0): *leaves crackling*  - [You Tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKfzhSWR1qc) *the sound of crackling leaves*.

> - I hear the leaves [crackling](https://books.google.it/books?id=plLMes5grAQC&pg=PA262&dq=%22leaves%20crackling%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMItZ70spSyyAIVTB8aCh3-JAtu#v=onepage&q=%22leaves%20crackling%22&f=false) under my feet as I trudge through the yard. I hear children yelling as they jump...

Answer (score 5):

The word *psithurism* means "the sound of wind in trees or rustling leaves" (not exactly what you were looking for).

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/psithurism

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/psithurism

Answer (score 4):

*Crinkle* is defined in [Merriam-Wester](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crinkle) as:

> to give forth a thin crackling sound :  rustle

Answer (score 4):

to describe the *movement* of the leaves ...

**swirling** or **dancing**

> [leaves swirling](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22leaves+swirling+in+the+wind%22&tbm=bks) / [dancing](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22leaves+dancing+in+the+wind%22) in the wind

As to their *sound*...

**blowing**

> *[the sound of leaves blowing](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22the%20sound%20of%20leaves%20crunching%22&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=634&tbm=bks&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0CA0Q_AUoAWoVChMImc-BobOyyAIVzNcUCh0TsAbl&dpr=1#tbm=bks&q=%22the%20sound%20of%20leaves%20blowing%22)*

**crunching**

> [*the sound of leaves crunching*](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22the%20sound%20of%20leaves%20crunching%22&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=634&tbm=bks&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0CA0Q_AUoAWoVChMImc-BobOyyAIVzNcUCh0TsAbl&dpr=1)

**crushed**

> *[The sound of leaves being crushed](https://books.google.it/books?id=C9N0BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA181&dq=%22the%20sound%20of%20leaves%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwADgoahUKEwjmoq7BtLLIAhVCuBQKHcpiA3E#v=onepage&q=%22the%20sound%20of%20leaves%22&f=false)*

**whispering**

> *[Sweetly swinging maple leaves, the weightless, softly swaying leaves, whispering leaves](https://books.google.it/books?id=O2QoAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&dq=%22leaves%20whispering%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwADgKahUKEwjc67jVtbLIAhWDvxQKHcd4C0E#v=onepage&q=%22leaves%20whispering%22&f=false)*,…

Answer (score 2):

The word is probably psithurism.

Reference :https://www.wordnik.com/words/psithurism

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a list](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/sounds-of-things-hitting-or-rubbing-together) of sounds for many sorts of physical interactions.  The only ones worth mentioning here are "rasping" and "scraping".

You could describe the sound instead; perhaps as "sibilant", as a "shushing" or "swishing" or "shuffling" sound, or with an onomatopoeia of your own invention.

Answer (score 0):

[And the leaves at my feet

**Whisper** sounds so familiar

Familiar, so familiar

Are you there? Are you there?](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/c/concrete+blonde/darkening+of+the+light_20033058.html)

*Darkening Of The Light* - Concrete Blonde